# C# how to get diagram name of element - Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I need to get diagram`s name of specific elements. Is it possible ?

I added elements note with specific stereotypu using profile to EA project. Then i want create a plugin where i find this notes and diagram names where they are located. (i want export notes and diagram names to excel)....PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a SQL like

```
Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT t_diagram.name FROM t_diagramobjects AS dobj INNER JOIN t_diagram  ON dobj.diagram_id = t_diagram.diagram_id WHERE  t_diagramobjects.Object_ID = <elementID>"
```

Just replace `<elementID>` with the element's elementID. You could alternatively retrieve the diagram GUID (`t_diagram.ea_guid') and get the diagram details via`Repostory.GetDiagramByGUID`.

Comment: I use your queary and it gives me this error https://ctrlv.sk/AF4r

Comment: You have to also remove the <> so it's like "object_id=105"

Comment: `string digname = Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT t_diagram.name FROM t_diagramobjects AS dobj INNER JOIN t_diagram  ON dobj.diagram_id = t_diagram.diagram_id WHERE  t_diagramobjects.Object_ID = "+eelementID.ToString());`                      i try it but then https://ctrlv.sk/a4Py

Comment: No picture, sorry.

Comment: https://ctrlv.sk/a4Py

Comment: Means your SQL is incomplete. Create a string first with the above and trace print that.